# Add or remove text from text file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm using PowerShell to add or remove text from file. I'm keep getting funny text in my file.

This only happens when I have removed the line from the text file and when I try to add new line I get funny text.

```
cls
IMPORT-MODULE ActiveDirectory

$fileLocation = "E:\Script\MatchCadTest\ptc.opt";

function addUser( $username=''){

    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    $userFullName = $user.Name;
    $empty = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($userFullName);

    if ( !($empty) ){
        $userExisted = Get-Content $fileLocation | Select-String "$username" -quiet

        if( ! $userExisted ){
            $newLocation =  "E:\Script\MatchCadTest\backup\";

            if((Test-Path -Path $fileLocation)) {
               Copy-Item "$fileLocation" "$newLocation"
            }

            $date = Get-Date -Format "d-M-y Hms";
            $newName = "ptc_$date.opt"
            Rename-Item "$newLocation\ptc.opt" $newName

            # Add-Content $fileLocation ""
            Add-Content  -Path $fileLocation -Value "# $userFullName";
            Add-Content  -Path $fileLocation -Value "INCLUDE MATHCAD USER $username";

            Write-Host "User has been added to file. Please restart the service." -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "User already existed" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White
        }
    }
}

function removeUser( $username=''){
    $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $username -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    # $user
    $userFullName = $user.Name;
    $empty = [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($userFullName);

    if ( !($empty) ){
        $userExisted = Get-Content $fileLocation | Select-String "$username" -quiet
        if( $userExisted ){
            $remove="# $userFullName";
            $removeUser = (Get-Content $fileLocation);
            $removeUser | where {$_ -ne $remove};

            $remove="INCLUDE MATHCAD USER $username";
            $removeUser | where {$_ -ne $remove}

            $removeUser |Out-File $fileLocation;

            #$removeUser = (Get-Content $fileLocation) | where {$_ -ne $remove} | Out-File $fileLocation;

            #$content = Get-Content $fileLocation
            #$content | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content $fileLocation

            Write-Host "User removed" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
        }
        else{
            Write-Host "User does not existed" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White
        }
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "User not found in ad" -BackgroundColor Red -ForegroundColor White
    }
}


$option=''
while ( $option -ne 0){

    Write-Host "What would you like to do?"
    Write-Host "1= Add new user"
    Write-Host "2=  Remove user"
    Write-Host "0= No (Exit)"

    $option = Read-Host "Select option"
    $username = Read-Host "Please enter Username"
    if( $option -eq 0 ){
        exit 1
    }

    elseif( $option -eq 1){
        addUser($username);
    }
    elseif ( $option -eq 22){
        removeUser ($username);
    }

    else{
        cls
        Write-Host
        Write-Host " Invaild Choice  " -BackgroundColor Red #-ForegroundColor White
        Write-Host
    }

    #Reset
    $option=444;
    $username="";
    $userFullName="";
    $user="";
    $empty="";
}
```

When I remove the line of text from file and add a new user, it's all a funny text string:

See below

‣潍慨浭摡䴠橡摩਍义䱃䑕⁅䅍䡔䅃⁄单剅洠ㅭ㘳㐰ല

I have a text file with following information.

```
- // Full name 1
- User ID of User 1

- // Full name 2
- User ID of User 2

* // Full name 3
* User ID of User 3

* // Full name 4
* User ID of User 4

* // Full name 5
* User ID of User 5

* // Full name 6
* User ID of User 6

* // Full name 7
* User ID of User 7

* // Full name 8
* User ID of User 8
```

If you see that  user 5 and 6 or 7 and 8 has extra space which i wont to remove and ad just sinlge space.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the encoding for your `Add-Content`

Try: `Add-Content  -Encoding UTF8 -Path $fileLocation -Value "# $userFullName";`

Comment: Is they any way i can remove lines from text file. for e.g. if they are two lines i wont to removed them but if they is single blank line between text then i wont to leave it.

Comment: @hello - I'm not sure I completely understand the question.  You should be able to compare line contents to each other, or use regular expressions to find specific content and perform deletes/removal based on it.  Can you provide an example of what you are asking here?

Comment: I have added more inforamtion at the top.

Comment: @hello - This should be straight forward.  Create a variable and every time you read a line store it in the variable.  Each line you read compare it to the line you have in your variable.  Then do a comparison similar to this: `If line1 == variable AND line1 == <Blanks> { delete line} else { Do nothing}`  This is just pseudo-code but I think you get the idea.